# Invalid Hook Call Error in react js, how can I use useState in class component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a class component, but it makes an error.

I know that code is Breaking the Rules of Hooks.

I'm wondering how I can use a `useState` hook within a class component.

I will use this component at the parent component so I must use class component

Here is the code snippet:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { createElement, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const [skill, setSkill] = useState([]);
    const [career, setCareer] = useState([]);
    const [education, setEducation] = useState([]);
    const [project, setProject] = useState([]);
    const [etcEducation, setEtcEducation] = useState([]);
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState([]);
    const [certificate, setCertificate] = useState([]);
    const [award, setAward] = useState([]);
    const [introduce, setIntroduce] = useState([]);
    
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const getUserIdx = localStorage.getItem('userIdx');
    const { portfolio_idx } = useParams();
    
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);
    
    // user 정보 get
    const getUserInfo = () => {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/users/${getUserIdx}`, {
        headers: {
          authorization: getToken,
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        const userData = res.data.data;
        setUserInfo(userData);
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    
    // portfolio get
    const getPortfolio = () => {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3001/portfolios/${portfolio_idx}`)
        .then((res) => {
          const datas = res.data.data;
          setSkill(datas.skill);
          setCareer(datas.career);
          setEducation(datas.education);
          setProject(datas.website);
          setLanguage(datas.language);
          setCertificate(datas.certificate);
          setEtcEducation(datas.etc_education);
          setAward(datas.award);
          setIntroduce(datas.introduce);
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err, '실패'));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      getUserInfo();
      getPortfolio();
    }, []);
        
    return () : null
  }
}
    
export default Portfolio;
```

Comment: Suggest another reading of the docs. You do not use hooks inside class components (you would use the constructor and `this.state`, lifecycle methods etc etc). Hooks are for functional components only.

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN'T** use the `useState` in class components.

Here is sample example of class components with states.

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here you can see `tick()` is using `this.setState()`. You can modify your state like that in **CLASS COMPONENTS**

Comment: i understand i CAN'T use the useState in class components.
and then, i wondering how to change useState into this.setState()?
can you make an one example in my code? thank you.

Comment: check the answer `tick()` method. That way, we set state in class components. Feel free if you still facing problems.